# BPMN schema basics

Tags: bpmn, bpmn.io

I'm trying to learn BPMN and display a simple process through a BPMN schema, just not sure how to display parts correctly, so far I have this: [image]

The process is actually like this:

1. A new employee is Created.
2. The employee data is Edited and Saved.
3. LDAP user creation:

   - if all required fields are filled - and there is no LDAP user created for that employee - LDAP user is created
   - if all required fields are filled - and there is an LDAP user for that employee - LDAP user is updated
4. if a system user doesn't exist - A new system user is created.

The 3rd and 4th processes are independent, however both are fired on saving the user data in the system.

I'm not sure exactly how many conditional paths I need to display the correct schema... Anyone can help out?

Comment: For the conditions use exclusive gateways

Answer (score 0):

Some activities sometimes required procedure in BPMN. Your point 3th and 4th: they are procedures for this two activities. It is not good idea to draw "all you know" as a diagram.

Probably your second stage is a use case creation.

See this:
https://www.visual-paradigm.com/tutorials/from-business-process-to-use-cases.jsp